# How can I get pyyaml.safe_load() to handle python/unicode tag?

Tags: python, pyyaml

We've a situation where we use yaml to pass some data in specific situations. We'd like to roll it out further, and I'm starting we should be using yaml.safe_load(). There is nothing particularly complicated about the yaml, but I notice a particular feature when the original string is unicode. For example:

```
>>> x = u"hello"
>>> x
u'hello'
>>> yaml.dump(x)
"!!python/unicode 'hello'\n"
```

If I try and read this in, I get an exception:

```
...
  File "f:\users\---\PyYAML-3.11-py2.7-win-amd64.egg.tmp\yaml\constructor.py", line 414, in construct_undefined yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag 'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/unicode'
  in "<string>", line 1, column 1:
    !!python/unicode 'hello'
```

I've seen it is possible to indicate classes are supported on safe_load, but this is not a user class. I could switch to using safe_dump(), but that would not work where the data has been written by an older version of one tool and read by a newer version of another (say).

So question: can I tell pyyaml that it can load python unicode strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know if there is a neater way, but I have found an answer...

```
>>> def constructor(loader, node):
...     return node.value
...
>>> yaml.SafeLoader.add_constructor("tag:yaml.org,2002:python/unicode", constructor)
>>> yaml.safe_load(y)
u'hello'
>>>
```

I guess it might be worth checking node.value actually is a unicode value, and in real code I'd structure it slightly different, but this works. Key is using:

```
yaml.SafeLoader.add_constructor()
```

instead of:

```
yaml.add_constructor()
```

I guess this goes down as using undocumented API, so any alternative answers would be interesting.